How to deal with a "Kernel Driver Not Installed (RC=-1908)" error when attempting to run Windows 10 on Virtual Box on a Linux Mint host?
I am new to Linux Mint and am trying to dip my toes in via my shop computer. I only use it to run my laser cutter, CNC, and 3D printers so I thought it would be a good place to start.
Some of the programs I am using are LightBurn, Carbide Create and Carbide Motion, and Prusa Slicer. I am currently trying to get Carbide Create and Carbide Motion working but they do not have a Linux version.
I am trying to use Virtual Box to run Windows 10 but am getting an error:

"Kernel Driver Not Installed (RC=-1908)"

I installed Virtual Box via the built in software store and I'm not sure how to fix the issue.
On top of that, I would rather not give Windows kernel level access to my computer as I don't trust them. Will this create a fake kernel for Virtual Box?
edit: as requested I need to clarify that the answer from VirtualBox Kernel driver not installed (rc=1908) did not help. As I wasn't getting any answers, I turned to chatGPT and after a few hours I got it working.
